# Java can't start RMI server

Tags: java, rmi, greenfoot

After installing avasty greenfoot a simple java programm to learn java isnt working on my windows 8 machine. In the log there is more information provided, but i as java beginner dont really understand the problem ! I hope somebody can help me!

```
Greenfoot run started: Thu Oct 24 17:29:03 CEST 2013
Greenfoot version: 2.3.0
Java version 1.7.0_21
Virtual machine: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.21-b01 (Oracle Corporation)
Running on: Windows 8 6.2 (x86)
Java Home: E:\jdk\jre
----
Internal error: Could not launch RMI server
Exception message: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at rmiextension.BlueJRMIServer.<init>(BlueJRMIServer.java:111)
    at rmiextension.RMIExtension.startup(RMIExtension.java:60)
    at bluej.extmgr.ExtensionWrapper.safeStartup(ExtensionWrapper.java:533)
    at bluej.extmgr.ExtensionWrapper.newExtension(ExtensionWrapper.java:209)
    at bluej.extmgr.ExtensionsManager.loadDirectoryExtensions(ExtensionsManager.java:164)
    at bluej.extmgr.ExtensionsManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionsManager.java:100)
    at bluej.extmgr.ExtensionsManager.getInstance(ExtensionsManager.java:61)
    at bluej.Main.processArgs(Main.java:179)
    at bluej.Main.access$000(Main.java:55)
    at bluej.Main$1.run(Main.java:97)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 29 more
Commencing network test...
Local host address = 212.5.13.214
Local host ip = 212.5.13.214
Addresses for 'localhost':
 -> 127.0.0.1
 -> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
(end of list).
Creating unbound server socket...
Successful.
Creating server socket bound to 127.0.0.1...
Successful.
Attempting to connect to 127.0.0.1:52317 with NO_PROXY...
(!!) Couldn't accept connection: Accept timed out
(!!) Exception class: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Creating server socket bound to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1...
Successful.
Attempting to connect to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:52319 with NO_PROXY...
Successful.
Attempting to connect to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:52319...
Successful.
Creating server socket bound to 212.5.13.214...
Successful.
Attempting to connect to 212.5.13.214:52322 with NO_PROXY...
(!!) Couldn't accept connection: Accept timed out
(!!) Exception class: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Network test complete.
(!!) Couldn't connect to local address: Connection refused: connect
(!!) Exception class: java.net.ConnectException
(!!) Couldn't connect to local address: Connection refused: connect
(!!) Exception class: java.net.ConnectException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a connection timeout to 127.0.0.1 there is something severely wrong with your network configuration.